# When does Callable lack __module__?

Tags: python, pycharm, typing, structural-typing

I am making a logging decorator for functions in python:

```py
import logging
from typing import Callable
from functools import wraps


def function_logging(fn: Callable) -> Callable:
    fn_logger = logging.getLogger(fn.__module__ + '.' + fn.__name__)

    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        fn_logger.info("Args: {}".format(args))
        fn_logger.info("Kwargs: {}".format(kwargs))
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        fn_logger.info("Return: {}".format(result))
        return result

    return wrapper
```

PyCharm's static analysis is telling me that I cannot expect a `Callable` to have the attribute `__module__`. So far I haven't encountered cases where this fails. Does anyone know under what circumstances one might encounter a `Callable` without the `__module__` attribute?

Comment: As far as I can tell, in general the only things with no `__module__` attribute are instances of builtin types. However, none of those are callable. I'm not sure if a metaclass can prevent the addition of a `__module__` on a class, its instances or its methods (and even if it can I'm not sure if it's safe). I was able to find a sort of fringe case. Method descriptors for builtin types, like `range.count` (which is callable) do not have `__module__`. On instances e.g. `range(0).count` the `__module__` is `None`, except for special methods e.g. `range(0).__str__` where it does not exist.

Comment: @jdehesa that could very well be it. Follow up: is there another type than `Callable` that would be appropriate to exclude these fringe cases?

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything more precise than `Callable` for that. I'm not even sure if those cases are supposed to behave like that and that's the reason for PyCharm to complain or if there's just no precise answer to the question "what things should or should not have `__module__`" in general. In any case, you can always do something like `(getattr(fn, '__module__', None) or '(none)')`.

Comment: I will note that `mypy` has no problem with this.

Comment: @modesitt `mypy` is generally a bit more well behaved than whatever PyCharm is using under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
list.__add__
```

That's a callable with no `__module__`. It's the unbound method for list concatenation.

In general, there's no requirement that callables have a `__module__`. It just has to be possible to call them. There's also no requirement that callables have a `__name__`, and for most callable types, it doesn't make sense to use `functools.wraps` with them.

Your decorator requires an instance of the ordinary Python function type; it cannot accept arbitrary callables. If you're going to give it type hints, you should hint it with that type:

```
def function_logging(fn: types.FunctionType) -> types.FunctionType:
    ...
```